# Child div causes parent div to occupy whole page width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div whose width changes based on text inside.

The parent div width is auto and child div  width is set to 100% which is the percent of parent div's width.

But the parent div occupies the whole page width. How can I maintain the minimum width of div to have the whole text in a single line while dynamically changing the text length.

Here is the  implementation

```css
.filled-no-icons {
    border-width:0px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    min-width:91px;
    min-height:36px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.filled-no-icons .rectangle-3 {
border-width:1px;
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-width:91px;
min-height:36px;
border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px ;
background-color:rgba(0,150.0,136.0,255);
left:0%;
top:0%;
}
.filled-no-icons .content {
    border-width:0px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    width:calc(100% - 32px);
    height:17px;
    min-width:59px;
    min-height:17px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    left:16px;
    top:calc(50% - 8.5px);
}
.filled-no-icons .content .label {
    border-width:1px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    width:calc(100% - 0px);
    height:17px;
    min-width:59px;
    min-height:17px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,255);
    font-family:Roboto-Medium;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:500;
    letter-spacing:0.75px;
    line-height:16.40625px;
    left:0px;
    top:calc(50% - 8.5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>
                Button test
            </title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="filled-no-icons">
        <div class="rectangle-3"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="label">Button</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Adding jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/3owturhc/

Comment: Use max-width: 100%; instead of width: 100%;

Comment: Then If I change the text inside to longer text it moves on to next line

Comment: Why is your html layout like this btw? Why do you need to have .rectangle-3 as a floating background instead of the .filled-no-icons being the background?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Yes, It's a bit weird. I am trying to write a css generator for figma design components. I am trying to write an auto CSS and HTML generator for design components.   Figma has groups/frames/layers etc with child components  so i am considering them as a HTML equivalent div which can contain other div's.

Comment: Once the base CSS generation is done I was planning on merging div's which are not necessary into parent div's.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's also the reason why you're using position:absolute inside the divs right? I think the divs with position:absolute are the ones making this difficult.

Comment: Yes, I had to position all the div's relative to their parent div, so I had to use position:absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you made such simple design into complicated HTML/CSS. But in general you can set the container to **`display: inline-block`** as it has the **shrink-to-fit** feature. Example below without any markup changes.

Don't set `.content` to absolute position. As if a container contains nothing but absolute positioned elements, it will collapse to nothing, only if you give it some size, but it will not be aware of the content inside, which means the box size cannot be dynamic.

```css
.filled-no-icons {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.filled-no-icons .rectangle-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 136, 255);
}

.filled-no-icons .content {
  position: relative; /* increase stacking order */
}
```

```html
<div class="filled-no-icons">
  <div class="rectangle-3"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="label">Button</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filled-no-icons">
  <div class="rectangle-3"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see why and how I ended up with the current HTML/CSS code in the comments of question. But is there any way this can be implemented without reducing/changing the existing hierarchy?

Comment: This makes sense, I have merged unnecessary divs into single div and removed position: absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Add display:inline-block; to the parent element. By default, a div has display:block which occupies the whole width or line. Run code below, thanks.

```css
.filled-no-icons {
    border-width:0px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    min-width:91px;
    min-height:36px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display:inline-block;
}
.filled-no-icons .rectangle-3 {
border-width:1px;
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-width:91px;
min-height:36px;
border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px ;
background-color:rgba(0,150.0,136.0,255);
left:0%;
top:0%;
}
.filled-no-icons .content {
    border-width:0px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    width:calc(100% - 32px);
    height:17px;
    min-width:59px;
    min-height:17px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    left:16px;
    top:calc(50% - 8.5px);
}
.filled-no-icons .content .label {
    border-width:1px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    width:calc(100% - 0px);
    height:17px;
    min-width:59px;
    min-height:17px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,255);
    font-family:Roboto-Medium;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:500;
    letter-spacing:0.75px;
    line-height:16.40625px;
    left:0px;
    top:calc(50% - 8.5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>
                Button test
            </title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="filled-no-icons">
        <div class="rectangle-3"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="label">Button</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I change the text inside to longer text it moves on to next line instead of expanding the div width